# Inline assembly language - Accessing an array's elements in C++

Tags: c++, windows, x86, inline-assembly

I'm upgrading a Borland C++ Builder 6 project to the latest Embarcadero C++ Builder (11.1)

It's a 32 bit windows app.

Some legacy code, not written by me, contains an array unsigned 32 bit integers, declared outside of a class like this:

```
UINT32 CRC32_TABLE[] =
    {
    0x000000000,0x077073096,0x0EE0E612C,0x0990951BA,
    0x0076DC419,0x0706AF48F,0x0E963A535,0x09E6495A3]; //the actual array is a lot bigger
```

Later on there is this function:

```
static UINT32 GenerateCRC(const void* p_data,
                      int         nbytes)
{
UINT32 rvalue;
__asm
    {
    mov esi,p_data
    mov ecx,nbytes
    mov ebx,0FFFFFFFFH          // Initialize CRC accumulator to -1

    /*--------------------------------------*/
    /* Accumulate the CRC in the specified  */
    /* range of memory.                     */
    /*--------------------------------------*/

loop2:                           // FOR i = 1 TO nbytes DO
    xor     eax,eax
    mov     al,[esi]             //   Get a byte to be checked
    inc     esi                  //   Bump index
    xor     al,bl                //   XOR NEW BYTE WITH LOW CRC
    shl     eax,2                //   MAKE IT A DWORD INDEX
    mov     edi,eax              //   
    shr     ebx,8                //   SHIFT OLD CRC RIGHT 8
    xor     ebx,CRC32_TABLE[edi] //   XOR SHIFTED CRC WITH CONSTANT
    loop    loop2                // ENDFOR
    not     ebx
    mov     rvalue,ebx
    }
return rvalue;
}
```

The current compiler wont accept xor ebx,CRC32_TABLE[edi], saying "cannot use a base register with variable reference".

It is decades since I've done any assembly language work, so any pointers to fixing this would be very much appreciated.

I'm very open to replacing the asm code with C++, btw. I have no idea why this code was written in  assembly language. It's not used in a time critical section but to verify logins... I'd like to think there was a better reason than 'because I could' but, judging from the C++ code, this was written by someone (sadly, no longer with us) who liked to complicate things for no reason...

Andy

Comment: I agree with the suggestion "rewrite in C++".  Do you have questions about how to do that?  It looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Or even better, assuming this is the standard CRC32 algorithm, replace with an off-the-shelf library implementation, which will likely be better optimized and which you won't have to debug.

Comment: My project has a TON of code written in lovingly hand-crafted assembly.  As a requirement, the dev also needs to provide a reference implementation in C++.  (And we automatically track performance trends over time, in case the assembly is for some reason becomes suboptimal.)  Now that we're moving to ARM, that's been a major win.

Comment: Nate - I'm ok with the doing the conversion. I did assembler in the 1990's so I understand what it's trying to do. This conversion project is huge, so if there was a quick win to fix the assembly code, I would use it. Otherwise, I'll do the conversion.

Yes - I like the idea of using a library (I already use Chilkat, which has this sort of thing) but we have a ton of customers where their CRC values are stored in databases and I doubt this bespoke CRC code would give the same results as an existing library...

Comment: You're sure `UINT32 CRC32_TABLE[] = {...};` is directly visible inside this compilation unit?  Does it help to make it `static const`?  Perhaps the compiler is worried about the `CRC32_TABLE[edi]` addressing mode in case that C++ variable is actually only in a shared library and it needs indirect access through dynamic linking?  Otherwise sounds like bad compiler support for inline asm; there's no reason that should be a problem.  Of course, it's not very efficient asm, failing to use movzx, not using scaled-index addressing, useless `mov` to EDI, and using the slow `loop` insn.

Comment: Do you think this is a custom CRC polynomial, other than standard CRC32 / CRC32C?  If so, then yeah you'd need a library that can optimize custom polynomials, maybe with a SIMD implementation, instead of using a hard-coded poly.  x86's `crc32` instruction uses the CRC32C polynomial, like iSCSI and many more modern protocols (and can accumulate 64 bits of data at a time.)

Comment: Peter - thanks for the suggestion. I will try the static const on Monday and see if it helps. I can also compare results from the CRC library I usually use and see how it compares to the BCB V6 compiled code. Maybe it will be compatible.

It's ironic that this code was written in assembly language that is inefficient. I wish my assembler wasn't so rusty, but it's almost 30 years since I did anything in it - on an the old 16 bit 8086 machine IIRC. Maybe I should pick it up again... Or maybe not :-)

Comment: Peter - making it a static const didn't help and Embarcadero's support basically said what we're doing is unsupported. Anyhow the Boost CRC library produces the same results as the assembly language, so I'll replace it with that.